# PHP Comparing objects - Strange behaviour

Tags: php, oop, object, compare

While **testing my own module for validation** I found some kind of problem.
I really don't know what is happening and **I can't explain it.**

Maybe I'm so tired or PHP is just freaking out.
Can **somebody tell me what is wrong ?**

I want to compare objects *(because I want to check that object already exists in array)*

**In PHP manual we can read:**

> **Comparing Objects**
>
> In PHP 5, object comparison is more complicated than in PHP 4 and more
>   in accordance to what one will expect from an Object Oriented Language
>   (not that PHP 5 is such a language).
>
> When using the **comparison operator (==)**, object variables are compared
>   in a simple manner, namely: **Two object instances are equal if they
>   have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same
>   class.**

So, Lets **create simple code** which will use it

```
class A
{
    protected $property;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->property = $value;
    }
}

$object1 = new A('ABC');
$object2 = new A('XYZ');

// Instances are not equal because of different value of property
var_dump($object1 == $object2); // Will return bool(false)
```

Ok, PHP told us the objects **are not equal** - **thats right.**

So now I decided to use objects of my class.
I provided different parameters to *constructor (those parameters will be set as class properites)*

```
echo "Start";

// Creating an instance of class with some parameters
// Each of parameter will be stored as class property
$object1 = new ComparsionRule('ABadasdC', ComparsionRule::LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);

// Creating an instance of class with some different parameters
// Each of parameter will be stored as class property
$object2 = new ComparsionRule('XYZ', ComparsionRule::NOT_EQUAL_TO);

// Two instances should not be equal (false expected)
var_dump($object1 == $object2); // Will return bool(true)

// Printing content of first object 
var_dump($object1);

// Printing content of second object
var_dump($object2);

// Checking the expression again
// Two instances should not be equal (false expected)
var_dump($object1 == $object2); // Will return bool(false)

echo "End";
die;
```

The result is surprising, for first PHP told us the objects **are equal** and then it printed those objects, after that it is **comparing objects again** but now objects **are not equal**.

**You can find result as image below:**

[image: Result]

I'm not using **any magic methods** *(excepts construct)* and I can't show content of *ComparsionRule* class *(prohibited by licence)*

**Another interesting fact:**

When I removed **$_errorDefinitions** property it started working properly. Similar when I changed properties order ($_type and $_compareValue defined earlier than $_errorDefinitions)

**I don't want to get alternative solution** I just want to **know why its working like this ?**

Can somebody explain me ?

Answer (score 3):

Because PHP is flipping insane!

```
<?php

class A {
    public $property;
    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->property = $value;
    }
}

$object1 = new A('Hello World');
$object2 = new A(0);

var_dump($object1 == $object2);
```

Don't rely on `==` to provide any meaningful comparison between PHP objects. If you need to check that two objects are the same instance, use `===`; otherwise add a meaningful comparison method to the class itself.

Without seeing the code for `ComparisonRule` I can't really hazard a guess at what's specifically going wrong. I'd normally assume some sort of lazy initialization of some of the object properties is going on, such that the properties are not initialized in your first comparison (and thus `==` sees them as equal), but get initialized by dumping the objects. However I don't think that's feasible without using some more magic methods.

Comment: Hmm, yea your example with int(0) and string cleared my mind.

I didn't noticed that PHP is comparing attributes values with "==" operator and I know that PHP is behaving strangely with it :)

I will check it and I will post answer soon.

Comment: I just added new answer with simple code which shows that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with it again and I **found something new**

I created **simple code** which shows this behaviour, so you don't need to see my class code anymore, because **you can test it by yourself now.**

So maybe now somebody will **explain what is happening ?**

```
<?php

// Printing "START"
echo 'START';

/**
 * Simple abstract class with one
 * protected property
 */
abstract class A
{
    /**
     * An errors array property
     * @var array
     */
    protected $errors = array();
}

/**
 * Simple class which extends A
 */
class B extends A
{
    /**
     * An errors array property
     * @var array
     */
    protected $errors = array();

    /**
     * Value from constructor
     * @var string
     */
    protected $value = null;

    /**
     * Method stores value in property
     * 
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $value  Value to store
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}

// Creating new instance of B with "ABC" string
$object1 = new B('ABC');

// Creating new instance of B with "CBA" string
$object2 = new B('CBA');

// Both objects got different value of $value property
// They should be different, but PHP returns true here
var_dump($object1 == $object2);

// Printing first object
var_dump($object1);

// Printing second object
var_dump($object2);

// Comparing objects again but now PHP returns false
var_dump($object1 == $object2);

// Printing "END"
echo 'END';
die;
```

Comment: I've managed to [reduce it still further](https://gist.github.com/tobyink/7945258). I can't see any logical reason for this to happen; it's almost certainly a bug in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it was a PHP bug, more details about that you can find below:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66286